# In angular, how can I use a component variable in scss file

Tags: css, angular, highcharts

My angular component configures a highchart(stacked bar chart). I need to take colors as input and set the colors to the bar chart. I am using "styled mode" of Highcharts, so I need to set the colors in scss file using .highcharts.color-0.

chart.component.ts

```
@Component({
selector: 'chart',
styleUrls: ['./chart.component.scss'],})
export class NwfStatusableDropdownComponent {

@Input() public color1;
public chart;
this.chart = new Chart() { //all chart config }
```

chart.component.scss

```
.highcharts-point.highcharts-color-0{
   fill: {{color1}},
 }
```

Comment: Please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: You can't do this. SCSS is not compiled at runtime, how should that work? You have to use the `Renderer2` to manipulate the element directly in your component or setup a style object and use it in your template (which you then manipulate).

Answer (score 0):

You should choose the esier way to implement.

In my case, I create an colors array variable in component

```
colors =  [ '#009ada', '#dc0004', '#72be00', '#b500c9', '#002ab4'];
```

And use it for setting color of highcharts series